# @media Print text-shadow under Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

When I add the css rule "**text-shadow**" for text it does not shown in **@media print** (save as PDF) and it does not work specially under **Chrome**.

It works excellent under IE11 but under Chrome - not!
It makes me very -very disappointed!

Here is the simple text-shadow example:

```
.item { text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ccc; }
```

So the question is how to force print "**text-shadow**" under **Chrome**?
In my case it also should be multiple shadows, something like that:

```
 .item { text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0px -1px 0 #fff; }
```

White border around a text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is **-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #ccc)**.

Here is the example:

```
@media print {
  /* CSS only for Chrome */
  @media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .item { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #ccc); }
  }
}
```

And if you need multiple text-shadows use it:

```
.item {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 0 0 #fff) drop-shadow(0 1px 0 #fff);
}
```

Here is the final CSS:

```
@media print {
  .item {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #ccc);
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand this answer right away, so here's the short version: For Chrome, just replace ```text-shadow: text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ccc;``` by ```-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 1px #ccc);``` No need to combine anything or to specify a media. BUT the end result in the PDF might be blurry, which is a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Nazar doesn´t seem to work on Chrome version 51.0.2704.103 m, I´m afraid. I can see the text-shadow using the debug menu "Rendering > Emulate media" and enabling the print mode. But when trying to print (actually saving as PDF) the shadows are not visible anymore. Also, I had to add this to make the text visible in the print preview:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0) !important;
```